# Call methods only ONCE per iteration

Tags: java, loops, oop

I'm running a simulation where the objects in my array get moved around by the three methods below. My simulation goes through many iterations (about 30). So that means I'm running move() 30 times.

Comment: Yes, a boolean flag should work, and why it's not is working is not something that I can readily see. Please consider creating and posting a valid [mcve] so that we can see why things are not working correctly. This should be a *small* program, posted with your question as code-formatted text, code that will compile and run for us without modification, and code that shows us your problem directly.

Comment: Move the boolean into the object. Loop object list on each array. Alternatively use a Map<Object, Boolean>. To other; looks like OP has a matrix and objects move along that matrix however they can only move once. Thus taking Boolean out of the loop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. I added some additional code. I included my implementation of move() that is found in my Carnivore class, and I included my cycle() method which is what calls everything together. Still trying to figure this out! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `static boolean` -- **static**??? Seriously, don't shoot yourself in the foot like this. Please.

Comment: @Frankie I like the idea. Can you show me just a few lines of what you mean to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

If you want each animal to move only once per iteration, then you need to mark which animals have already moved.

Right now you have just one boolean var for the whole Ecosystem class, that's not enough to mark each moved object.

You can use a Set to store the animals you already moved.

Add this in the Ecosystem class:

```
private Set<Animal> alreadyMoved;
```

Then in the beginning of each cycle, create a new Set to start from scratch:

```
alreadyMoved = new HashSet<Animal>();
```

Then in the move method:

```
public synchronized void move() {

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

            if (ecosystem[i][j] != null) {

                if (!alreadyMoved.contains(ecosystem[i][j]) {

                     // move it

                     alreadyMoved.add(ecosystem[i][j]);

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of other ways to do it:

1. Instead of a boolean, give each animal an extra integer field that contains the last iteration (no) that it moved in.
2. Have 2 `ecosystem` arrays, one representing "this iteration" and the other representing "the last iteration".  Either flip them and null out the "this iteration" array at the start of a new iteration, or just allocate a new array and let the old one be GC'd.